# How to add a dot in a function

Tags: javascript

```
let username = "Furkan";

function showMessage() {
  let message = "Hello, " + username;
  alert(message);
}

showMessage();
```

I want the message to show "Hello, Furkan." Not "Hello, Furkan"

Edit: Thank you for your answers guys. I'm very new to JavaScript. I'm sorry.

Comment: `let message = "Hello," + username + ".";`

Comment: Add `+ "."` to the message initialization expression. Does this really warrant a question? You've got the code right there already that creates the message as it stands.

Comment: Your current function will NOT show "Hello, Furkan", it WILL show "Hello,Furkan", because there is no space after the comma in the String in `message`...  
So: `message = "Hello, " + username + "."` will show what you want, or, string literal, as @Mehraz suggested, `message = \`Hello, ${username}.\``.  
Also, indent/align `let username` to the left, same as `function`.

Comment: Your general problem is how to concatenate strings (put them together to create a longer string), so the answer is already in the code. You can see `"Hello," + "Furkan"` gives "Hello,Furkan", so the concatenation operator in JS is `+`. It's like if `2 + 2` gives `4`, how do I make the result 5 instead? Well, we can see the `+` symbol performs addition on numbers, so we can try `2 + 2 + 1`.

Comment: Furkan, you are welcome!  Glad to help!
Perhaps the "mis-indentation" before was a one time glitch, but if not, and because I'm assuming you are new to coding (JavaScript, at least), I'd like to recommend getting used to indentation (based on scope-level, etc.) = this will make your code more readable to you and anyone else.  And keep being consistant! (semicolons (perhaps add after closing of function), spaces around "=" & "+", space between "function ....()" and "{").  It's better to have an "extra" semicolon that getting stuck on a bug you cannot find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elegant solution is the one above

```
let message = `Hello, ${username}.`;
```

the easier to understand based on your function and clearly because you are a beginner

```
let message = "Hello," + username + ".";
```

Answer (score 1):

alternate this code.

```
let message = `Hello, ${username}.`;
```